# When does speculation become evil gossip?

Tags: lashon-hara-slander

All we know about the death of Nadav and Avihu is this verse in Leviticus:

*And Nadav and Avihu, the sons of Aaron, took each of them his censer, and put fire in it, and put incense on it, and offered strange fire before the Lord, which He did not command them.   And there went out fire from the Lord and devoured them, and they died before the Lord. [Leviticus 10:1-2]*

The commentators tell us that they died because they did not take counsel from each other [Lev. Rabbah 20:6]; because they were drunk with wine, wore improper clothing, did not wash their hands and feet, and had no children [Lev. Rabbah 20:9]; because they had no wives and did not believe any woman was worthy of them [Lev. Rabbah 20:9]; because they were anxious for Moses and Aaron to die so they could take over [Sanhedrin 52a]; because they gave a legal decision in the presence of their master Moses [Eruvin 63a, Lev. Rabbah 20:6]; because their father Aaron helped make the Golden Calf [Rashi on Deut. 9:20]; etc.

This is disturbing.  Sure, we speculate because we want to understand the reasons for these deaths so we don't make the same mistake ourselves.  But when does this speculation constitute dumping on the deceased by creatively trying to find fault with them?  Is it rabbinically-sanctioned lashon hara, the evil tongue?  What should be its limits?

(My personal view is the plain pshat.  God said, "OK, this is the beginning of Judaism and I must set the tone NOW.  You will perform the commandments EXACTLY as ordered, or else.  No variation whatsoever is allowed.  Because if I allow variations, before too long you will be sacrificing your children to me to show me your great devotion, torture animals to death to offer me their pain, and other such nonsense, and I don't want any of that.")

So:  What should be the limits of allowed speculation on the reasons for events, especially when this speculation tarnishes the reputation of people?

Comment: Shabbat 96b: *Our Rabbis taught: The gatherer was Zelophehad. And thus it is said, and while the children of
Israel were in the wilderness, they found a man [gathering sticks, etc.]; whilst elsewhere it is said,
our father died in the wilderness; just as there Zelophehad [is meant], so here too Zelophehad [is
meant]: this is R. Akiba's view. **Said R. Judah b. Bathyra to him, ‘Akiba! in either case you will have
to give an account [for your statement]: if you are right, the Torah shielded him, while you reveal
him; and if not, you cast a stigma upon a righteous man.’***  (My emphasis)

Comment: -1 I think you should be more neutral when asking questions about judging the Sages. I think "Can an interpretation become Lashon Harah" is something neutral, where "*When it becomes evil*" reveals your intentions.

Comment: @AlBerko Downvotes are for posts that are “not useful.” Does a poor motivation make the question inherently a bad question?

Comment: @DonielF I did this mistake myself and now I'm trying to avoid it as possible. In a respectful site, the questions should be asked in a neutral form like "was he bad" or "is it Lashon Harah", but not taking a side and judging, like "why he was so bad" or "isn't this clearly a Lashon Hara". **The question is good, but it is phrased in a very judging form like the OP's intention to promote his own view instead of hearing others**.

Comment: I see no difference in tone between your title and mine. They are both neutral. I have reinstated my original title.  I wish we would talk about my question instead.